# Self-signed SSL certificates and stringWithContentsOfURL

Tags: ssl, network-programming, ios, self-signed

I am requesting some data from a server with `NSString#stringWithContentsOfURL:`. The server is using a self-signed certificate, so `stringWithContentsOfURL:` simply returns nil and does not give a change to accept the certificate.

This is all expected behaviour. I know how to properly do this with `NSURLConnection` and it's delegate methods instead, but I am looking for a shorter term fix instead of rewriting this code. (Yay deadlines)

So my question is, is it possible to import the self-signed certificate into the application's keychain, and will that cause `stringWithContentsOfURL:` to accept the self-signed certificate?

Comment: I'm having this issue. How did you solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I beleive that there is an enterprise tool from Apple for installing SSL certs -- it was necessary to get exchange mail working.

You may also be able to mail the .cer file to yourself, open on your iPhone and install it.

There is also the [AdvancedURLConnections sample project](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedURLConnections/Introduction/Intro.html) from Apple

> This sample demonstrates various
>   advanced networking techniques with
>   NSURLConnection. Specifically, it
>   demonstrates how to respond to
>   authentication challenges, how to
>   modify the default server trust
>   evaluation (for example, to support a
>   server with a self-signed
>   certificate), and how to provide
>   client identities.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to go around that SSL verification scheme, and after a while of trying and looking all over the place for a solution, I had to implement a class to do just that.

Since the advantage of NSString's stringWithContentsOfURL is to be synchronous, I had to make sure mine was as well. It's probably a little big for every purpose, but you get the gist of it.

```
@interface NZStringLoader : NSObject
@property (assign, readonly, nonatomic) BOOL done;
@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) NSString *result;
@property (strong, readonly, nonatomic) NSURLConnection *conn;

- (id) initWithURL:(NSURL*)u;
- (void) loadSynchronously;

@end

@implementation NZStringLoader

@synthesize done = _done, result = _result, conn = _connection;

- (id) initWithURL:(NSURL*)u {
    NSURLRequest *req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:u
                                              cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringCacheData
                                          timeoutInterval:10.0];
    _connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:req delegate:self];
    _done = NO;

    return self;
}

- (void) loadSynchronously {
    [_connection start];

    while(!_done)
        [[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] runUntilDate:[NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:.15]];
}

#pragma mark -
#pragma mark NSURLConnectionDelegate

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response {
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection {
    _done = YES;
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error {
    RTLog(@"%@", [error localizedDescription]);
    _done = YES;
}

- (BOOL)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection canAuthenticateAgainstProtectionSpace:(NSURLProtectionSpace *)protectionSpace {
    return [protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge {
    if ([challenge.protectionSpace.authenticationMethod isEqualToString:NSURLAuthenticationMethodServerTrust])
        [challenge.sender useCredential:[NSURLCredential credentialForTrust:challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust] forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];

    [challenge.sender continueWithoutCredentialForAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data {
    if(_result == nil)
        _result = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    else
        _result = [_result stringByAppendingString:[[NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
}

@end
```

And it's used like this:

```
    NZStringLoader *sl = [[NSStringLoader alloc] initWithURL:u];
    [sl loadSynchronously];
    result = sl.result;
```

I guess I could make it just one call, if I wanted to.